# Swift : Wrong character in String

Tags: json, string, swift, character-encoding

i'm parsing a UTF8 Json, and i don't understand why the degree symbol "°" is wrong when i try to show it in a UILabel.
I get a strange question mark symbol inside a black shape [�C].

To parse JSON i use this method:

```
    if let data = dataToParse{
        do {
            parsedConfigurationObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        }catch{

        }
    }else{

    }
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: How did you build/send this JSON from your web service, because usually this stuff is handled properly if you used standard mechanisms (e.g. if using PHP, used `json_encode` rather than building it yourself, manually)?

Comment: in JSON it is correct, but when i deserialize the string i get that strange char..

Comment: Can you add some code in your question?

Comment: solved, it was a mistake in JSON!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your UTF8 Json. Have you try to encoding your data with UTF8?

```
extension String {
    func utf8() -> NSData? { return (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) }
}
```

Use:

```
"{}".utf8()
```

Comment: tried it, but not working :( i still get that strange character. as mentioned before, in JSON i can see that the degree symbol is correct, but when i deserialize the string, i get the bad char